# How can I split string based on combination of characters?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have this string: 
`'Hello my Name is #!Jospeh#!'. I want my Output to be Jospeh.`

Lets say if i have this string:
`'Hello my Name is #!Joseph#! #!King#!'. I want my Output to me 'Joseph' and 'King'`

I have created a function:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[TfSplitTemplateVariable]
    (
      @String NVARCHAR(4000) ,
      @Delimiter NCHAR(2)
    )
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
    (
    WITH    Split ( stpos, endpos )
              AS ( SELECT   0 AS stpos ,
                            CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @String) AS endpos
                   UNION ALL
                   SELECT   endpos + 1 ,
                            CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @String, endpos + 1)
                   FROM     Split
                   WHERE    endpos > 0
                 )
    SELECT  'Id' = ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY ( SELECT    1
                                                ) ) ,
            'Data' = SUBSTRING(@String, stpos,
                               COALESCE(NULLIF(endpos, 0), LEN(@String) + 1)
                               - stpos)
    FROM    Split
)
GO
```

And when i run this:

```
SELECT tstv.* FROM dbo.TfSplitTemplateVariable('Hello my Name is #!Jospeh#!','#!') AS tstv  WHERE   ID % 2 = 0
```

I get output `!Jospeh`.
What am i doing wrong

Comment: You might want to read this article written by Dwain Camps: [Split Strings Based on Patterns](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/String+Manipulation/94365/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `SELECT endpos + 1` to `SELECT endpos + LEN(@Delimiter)`.

Comment: Instead hard-code to 2, it should be `SELECT endpos + LEN(@Delimiter)`

Answer (score 0):

I hope this code suite your needs:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[TfSplitTemplateVariable]
    (
      @String NVARCHAR(MAX),
      @Delimiter NVARCHAR(2)
    )
RETURNS @result TABLE (Id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, Data NVARCHAR (MAX))
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @start INT, @end INT
    SET @start = 1

    WHILE CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @String, @start) > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @start  = CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @String, @start) + LEN(@Delimiter)
        SET @end    = CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @String, @start)

        IF @end > @start
        BEGIN
            INSERT @result(Data) VALUES(SUBSTRING(@String, @start, @end - @start))
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            BREAK
        END

        SET @start = @end + LEN(@Delimiter)
    END

    RETURN
END
GO
```